# In my template [!h] isn't working

Tags: floats

In my current template that is based on an APA 6 manuscript ([Link to the template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/your-apa6-style-manuscript/kngbbqpypjcq#.WBNqLfqLTmE)) the `[!h]` function doesn't work. It keeps putting images on seperate pages at the bottom of the manuscript.

(tried all variants of `[!htbp]`, etc)

Hopefully someone is able to help!

Comment: `[!h]` is quite, shall we say, underpowered. It will do its best to place the figure there, but aesthetic concerns will quickly beat it and if TeX can't find a good way of placing your figure there, it won't place it there. See this really comprehensive question for more info http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020

Comment: Welcome, `[!h]` does not prevent a figure box from floating around. A common misconception.

Comment: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: If you really must have it **here** and you want a rather quicker answer to that question, you might try this thread http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Comment: the main effect of `[!h]` is that it prevents latex placing the float at top or bottom of a page or on a float page, so it leaves latex little choice but to float to the end of the document that's why it gives a warning and is changed to [ht] in most cases (but that is still restrictive)

Answer (score 4):

As documented in the apa6 manual, by defaults floats will go to the end of the manuscript as required by their publication systems, you can use the `floatsintext` option to give normal latex behaviour.

Note however in the normal latex float positioning you should normally avoid `[!h]` as it is very restrictive and gives latex very few options to place the float. (It will usually give a warning and change this to `[!ht]`)